# Web scraping from JSP in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr, rselenium

I am trying to extract the table from this [link](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=sbin&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=24month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE) into R.
The table is the stock price for **SBIN** for the past **24 months**. Here is the [original site.](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm)

I tried using `RSelenium` and `httr` package as suggested from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305824/extracting-data-from-javascript-with-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596714/how-to-scrap-a-jsp-page-in-r/50598032) but couldn't extract the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data with `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=sbin&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=24month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE'

url %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] -> result

result
```